# PHP | imagecopymerge() won't work

Tags: php, php-gd

```
        $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
        $src = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');

        // Copy and merge
        imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 50, 50, 0, 0, 30, 30, 75);

        imagepng($dest, '1.png');

        imagedestroy($dest);
        imagedestroy($src);
```

$dest = 50x50
$src = 30x30
1.png only shows the $dest image with out the $src on top of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dest is 50x50, then you're trying to copy from the bottom right corner, which has 50, 50 as coordinates.

```
 +-----------------------+
 |                       |
 |                       |
 |     you should copy   |
 |                       |
 |                       |
 |                       |
 |     there             |
 |                       |
 |                       |
 |                       |
 |                       |
 +-----------------------+-----------------------+
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |    you're copying     |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |       here            |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                         +-----------------------+
```

Comment: Now, How can I place it with transparent edges on the other one?

Comment: @askingDude: I don't understand what you mean by "transparent edges", but if I ignore this part of the sentence, I would say, by changing the coordinates to something less than 50, 50. If you do so, you should see something and then proceed with trial and error...

Comment: Yes, this worked out:
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 25, 25, 0, 0, 25, 25, 100);
And the second img is 25 pix now.
But my second image is a circle, and it shows white edges until it looks like a box, how can I get rid of the white edges? *.png?

Comment: After reading the manual, it seems that you shouldn't get these white edges with your last parameter... are you sure these edges do not appear on the original image?

Comment: I mean that I want my image to have no white edges and I removed them via photoshop, but they somehow are still there, maybe because of the image format?

Comment: png supports transparency, so the image your getting with imagefrompng should be fine. Try outputting it directly, without doing the imagecopymerge just to see if it is fine.